# discord.py welcome event keeps sending after the member joined

Tags: python, discord.py

I am working with Python in Discord. It works correctly when a member joins, but it continues to send the message repeatedly afterwards, as well.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(1119942896309784576)
    if isinstance(channel, discord.TextChannel):
        welcome_message = f"{member.mention} welcome to My Server!\n\nPlease check the channels below:\n\n"\
                          f"<#{1119942908615872542}>\n<#{1119942920695451698}>\n<#{1119942922247348326}>\n<#{1119942952572178452}>"
        await channel.send(welcome_message)
```

Comment: quick update it seems to be sending over and over because its reading when a member joins any of the server that the bots in and sending it to the one channel is there a way to limit it to the one server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you are trying to limit it to one server.

All you have to integrate is a simple check after the actual join event.

**The check:**

```py
if member.guild.id == IdOfTheServer: # Replace with your server ID
   # The rest of your code if it's the correct server
```

**Your new code could look like this:**

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if member.guild.id == IdOfTheServer: # Replace with the server ID
        channel = member.guild.get_channel(ChannelID)
        welcome_message = f"Your Message"
        await channel.send(welcome_message)
    else:
        return # Do nothing as it's not the correct server
```

Keep an eye on the further changes I made:

- Changed `client.get_channel` to `member.guild.get_channel` in assumption that the channel is on the server the member joins
- Removed the `if isinstance(channel, discord.TextChannel)` check as it's not needed if you pass the ID of a text channel